# Remove style id inline CSS in WordPress

Tags: themes, css

When I fix CSS error in my site I can't find these errors. How can I find this CSS in my site?

> `<style id='onetone-main-inline-css' type='text/css'>`

When I check it show many errors in CSS so I want to fix it and I can't find where this is that I can fix the error.

I am using **onetone** theme.

So if anyone know please help

Comment: Since your theme's name is "onetoone" it's likely that it's coming from your theme, but plugins can also add CSS. The quickest way to tell whether it's a plugin or your theme is to switch themes briefly and see if the code is still there. If it is, it's a plugin, so you can switch back to your usual theme, deactivate plugins, then activate one by one until you find the plugin that's adding the CSS.

Comment: Thanks, let me try. but i don't use any plugin name onetone. it's only my theme name is onetone.